# размер массива с++

Tags: c++

Есть такая строчка:

```
int a[10];
cout << sizeof(a); // 40
```

Размер массива это его длина, верно? То есть можно написать:

```
 cout << sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); // 10, тут все понятно.
```

Но в 1 примере непонятно почему ответ 40 объясните пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
int main(){
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
        cout<<arr[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Что здесь делает `cin>>arr[i]`? Вводит элементы массива? А это разве не индексы массива, а не сами элементы, или как.

Comment: Это размер в байтах. То, что вы хотите, в С++ `std::size(a)`.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за ответ. Я также подумал, только у меня не вышло потому что синтаксис неверный указал - a.size(). Спасибо.

Comment: Используте `std::array<int, 10>` у него есть метод `.size()`

Comment: @user7860670 ошибку дает. когда хочу поменять местами элементы массива. в таком коде: ` std::array<int,10>;//1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 10
 for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
  cout<<arr[(n-1)-i] << " ";
 }`

Comment: @user7860670 компилятор ругается говоря что `array is not member of std::`

Comment: Ну так необходимо заголовочный файл соответствующий включить

Comment: @user7860670 оу, точно, забыл совсем, спасибо

Comment: @user7860670 я добавил код там, с вопросом, можете пожалуйста посмотреть и написать как ответ, я отмечу его. Не понимаю как это работает. это индексы элементов или сами элементы?

Comment: Индекс элемента - это то, что в квадратных скобках. А результат оператора квадратных скобок - это ссылка на сам элемент.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть `cin>>arr[i]` вводит индекс или сам элемент? как понять эту строчку объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Я же уже написал, то что в квадратных скобках (`i`) - это индекс, а результат оператора (`arr[i]`) - это ссылка на сам элемент. В него потом и происходит ввод.

Comment: @user7860670, а почему нельзя написать cin>>i ?

Comment: ¿С чего вы решили, что так нельзя? Там же выше написано `cin>>n;`

Comment: @user7860670 это ввод числа, а если в массив добавлять то вместе cin>>arr[i] можно написать cin>>i ?

Comment: нет, конечно, если написать `cin>>i`, то это будет ввод числа в `i`

Comment: Размер статического массива должен быть известен на этапе разработки. Соответственно, он должен задаться или литералом, или константой, или выражением, зависящем только от констант и/или литералов, или вообще неявно.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)` возвращает размер в байтах, а `std::size(a)` - в элементах.

Соответственно, 40 и 10.